# WAMP: Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. #2002 mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am running 2 locally hosted wp sites for testing on my Win 7 pc. Unfortunately windows update did a update install and reboot last night while wamp was online.
Usually I can fix this myself, but I am having no luck. After about 6 hours of search for a resolution I turn to you wonderful people.

PROBLEM: Orange Icon. 
         PhpMyAdmin error #2002

Here is my error log:

```
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked     functions            
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 12054850 and 12054850 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 12746597 in the ib_logfiles!
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-02-25 13:12:44 4420 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace dlkei4n83xuf/rvcommentmeta uses space ID: 11 at filepath: .\dlkei4n83xuf\rvcommentmeta.ibd. Cannot open tablespace test/rvscommentmeta which uses space ID: 11 at filepath: .\test\rvscommentmeta.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\test\rvscommentmeta.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: The message about FEDERATED being disabled is not relevant. If you look it is just a [Note]. If you read the actual error messages i.e. everything that follows the first [ERROR] it basically tells you how to attempt to fix the database crash. FOLLOW THE INSTRUCTIONS

Comment: Refer
(http://stackoverflow.com/a/37723811/4255461 "refer this link it solved my problem ")