# what is the problem in Illuminate\Database\QueryException?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I found this problem ""lluminate\Database\QueryException

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it.

[image]

Comment: are you sure of that the mysql service is running?

Comment: i think so.any solution??

Comment: run wamp or xamp if they are not already running

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523298/error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-mac)