# Unable to save static data using symfony

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I want to save static data values into php myadmin database table, with symfony. but when I used to run my save route, it shows an error:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

My table with name article and fields are created successfully.

TestController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Article;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/save")
     */

    public function save(): Response{
        $entitymanager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $article = new Article();

        $article->setTitle('Test');
        $article->setBody('This is the test');

        $entitymanager->persist($article);

        $entitymanager->flush();
        return new Response('Saved');
    }

}
```

Article.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticleRepository::class)
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=20)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $body;



    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title; 
    }

    public function getBody(){
        return $this->bdoy;
    }

    public function setTitle($title){
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function setBody($body){
        $this->body = $body;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the server, rather than code. Are you sure that your SQL server is running?

Comment: You need check the database config

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523298/error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-mac)